# Prove that ED=EF

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation, congruences-geometry

> In the diagram below $AD=DC$ and $AE=EB$ and both triangles $AEB$ and $ADC$ are right angel triangles and $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$ also $MD=MF$. 
>   Prove that $ED=EF$

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join $BF$.

$\triangle BMF\cong \triangle CMD$ by SAS, so
$$\begin{align*}
BF&= CD\\
\angle MBF &= \angle MCD\\ &= \angle MCA + 45^\circ
\end{align*}$$

Consider angles around point $B$,

$$\begin{align*}
\angle EBF &= 360^\circ - \angle EBA - \angle ABM - \angle MBF\\
&= 360^\circ - 45^\circ - \angle ABM - (\angle MCA + 45^\circ)\\
&= 270^\circ - \angle ABM -\angle MCA\\
&= 45^\circ + (180^\circ -\angle ABM - \angle MCA) + 45^\circ\\
&= \angle EAB + \angle BAC + \angle CAD\\
&= \angle EAD
\end{align*}$$

So $\triangle EAD\cong \triangle EBF$ by SAS,  and

$$ED=EF$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a rotation around $D$ for $90^{\circ}$ and let $\mathcal{Z}$ a reflection across $M$. Then we see that composition $\mathcal{J}=   \mathcal{Z}\circ \mathcal{R}$     of these two transformation is also rotation for $270^{\circ} =-90^{\circ}$ around some point $X$. Now since $$ \mathcal{J}:   A\mapsto C\mapsto B$$ we see that $E$ is a center of this new rotation $\mathcal{J}$. But $$ \mathcal{J}:   D\mapsto D\mapsto F$$ we see it take $D$ to $F$ and so $EF = ED$ (and $\angle FED = 90^{\circ}$)